# Outlook OfficeJS itemID with slashs return error from MS graph

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an Outlook Add-in that grabs the ItemID from OfficeJS, passes this back to a express server, that forwards the message through Graph API forward endpoint.

Normally I get ItemID's that look something like this that the Graph API forwards correctly:

`AQMkADAwATNiZmYAZC1mZDMyLTJjODAtMDACLTAwCgBGAAAD6HpLXdIWSkydFpIOnccszQcAa+WVq3+CfU+sUUEjYH6kNXXXXXXa+WVq3+CfU+sUUEjYH6kNAAAANor+k8AAAA=`

The problem I am having is in some instances I get an ItemID like this:

`AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS1hYzNiLWY1MjAtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADt9wSOQ+Jc0urM7fl9yLPMwcAKzExAL5p8QNFrnWOneViFEwXXXXXXCsxMQC+afEDRa51jp3lYhRMAAHjntX/AAAA`

Notice the `/` right before the trailing `AAAA`.

So I then encode the URI component and fire off a request to:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS1hYzNiLWY1MjAtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADt9wSOQ%2BJc0urM7fl9yLPMwcAKzExAL5p8QNFrnWOneViFEwXXXXXXCsxMQC%2BafEDRa51jp3lYhRMAAHjntX%2FAAAA/forward
```

And I get this response:

```
"error":{
    "code":"BadRequest",
    "message":"Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery: users/rando@outlook.com/messages/AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS1hYzNiLWY1MjAtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADt9wSOQ+Jc0urM7fl9yLPMwcAKzExAL5p8QNFrnWOneViFEwXXXXXXCsxMQC+afEDRa51jp3lYhRMAAHjntX/AAAA/forward",
    "innerError":{
        "request-id":"6b3a8b34-4474-4260-98d4-107b1dfd4cc4",
        "date":"2017-08-04T18:02:10"
    }
}
```

Has anyone come across this or know a solution? This seems like it may be a problem on Microsofts end when a `/` is in the ItemId.

Note: Some sanitation was done on the posted user and ItemIds.

Comment: Have you attempted to find the message with the `id` in Graph Explorer? I'm curious what the Graph sees for an ID in this scenario.

Comment: I end up getting the same error that I received from my API call, `Unsupported segment type`. Ping me if you want the exact ItemID if you want to give it a shot.

Comment: I was suggesting looking up the message in Explorer to see what the "real" Id is from Graphs perspective. I expected using the Id itself would give you the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, if anyone else has this issue, from the depths of the internet I found this:

`The same ID in order to be processed by the Office 365 Unified API would need to be slightly altered by replacing all / (slash) characters with a - (dash):`

Verified this to work. If anyone has a link to the MS Docs that state this you would have my +1.

Answer (score 6):

The id returned by [Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item#nullable-itemid-string) is an EWS item id. As you noticed, the REST id has a slightly different format.

The [Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox#converttorestiditemid-restversion--string) add-in API will convert the EWS item id to a REST/Graph item id, which your add-in can then send up to your server.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Graph API endpoint which does what you want: it converts EWS IDs into REST IDs. From the docs (link is below):

> Translate identifiers of Outlook-related resources between formats.

Supported formats are:

entryId - The binary entry ID format used by MAPI clients.

ewsId - The ID format used by Exchange Web Services clients.

immutableEntryId - The binary MAPI-compatible immutable ID format.

restId - The default ID format used by Microsoft Graph.

restImmutableEntryId - The immutable ID format used by Microsoft Graph.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-translateexchangeids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0):

To expand the previous answer given by gr347wh173n0r7h and Haris Osmanagić, you can use Graph API to translate.

If you do it by hand, here are replacements to be applied:

- the restId to the ewsId:

  - '_' -> '+' & '-' -> '/'
- the ewsId to the restId:

  - '+' -> '_' & '/' -> '-'